# Function Naming

Tags: notation

If I have

$$\frac{dx}{d\tau}=x(1-x) -h\frac{x}{a+x}$$

and I want to name this function, is it appropriate to call it $f\left(x, a, h\right)$?

I've seen it done for one parameter, e.g. if just $x$ and $a$ were in the function it would be $f\left(x,a\right)$.

Or should I just not mention the parameters at all?

Thanks.

Comment: What function ? What you wrote is an equation.

Comment: I want to rename $\frac{dx}{d\tau}$ as a function of x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the expression can be viewed as a function of three variables that is

$$f(x,h,a)=:x(1-x) -h\frac{x}{a+x}$$

but the final choice depends by the context and notably from which ones are defined are variables and which ones are assumed as parameters.

Comment: In this case x is the variable and a and h are parameters, so would it be more suitable to just call it $f\left(x\right)$?

Comment: @sandbag66 Yes in that case $f(x)$ is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $f(x)$, or, if you want to stress the dependency on "parameters", $f(x;a,h)$. Could also be $f_{a,h}(x)$.

Comment: How common is the semicolon notation? Is it found in certain branches of mathematics more than others?

Comment: @sandbag66: no idea, but I don't think it matters.